# implementing image classification in rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have implemented an example of classifying cats and dogs using cnn. You can get the code from [here](https://github.com/venkateshtata/cnn_medium./tree/master) and [here](https://becominghuman.ai/building-an-image-classifier-using-deep-learning-in-python-totally-from-a-beginners-perspective-be8dbaf22dd8). I want to do the same but with RNN.

How to do that? I want to use my own dataset.

Below you find the code I used with my own datast:

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 
'relu'))
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())
# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics 
= ['accuracy'])
# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.2,
zoom_range = 0.2,
horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
steps_per_epoch = 8000,
epochs = 25,
validation_data = test_set,
validation_steps = 2000)
# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', 
target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
prediction = 'dog'
else:
prediction = 'cat'
```

Answer (score 3):

Keras provides an example of how to classify the [MNIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) dataset using an [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_irnn.py). You can replace their dataset with yours, adjust the number of classes and you should be done.

Comment: Keras link doesn't work anymore but I found this instead https://www.kaggle.com/muhammedfathi/mnist-with-rnn-and-lstm